# Converting float to double loses precision C#

Tags: c#, types, casting, floating-point

I have the following code

```
    double temp3 = 61.01;

    //This can actually be various other types, but float is the one that causes problems
    dynamic temp = 61.01f;
    double temp2 = (double)Convert.ChangeType(temp, typeof(double));

    double newValue = temp2 - temp3;

    //newValue should == 0 but it does not

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", temp));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", temp2));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", temp3));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", newValue));
```

Which produces

61.01000000000000000000

61.00999832153320000000

61.01000000000000000000

-0.00000167846679488548

Why is Convert.ChangeType losing precision?

We are using Convert.ChangeType because of the use of a dynamic variable which can be byte/uint/float/double etc

Comment: I'm fairly certain the answer will still be the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Your source data type is `float`, and `.01` can't be accurately represented in binary: `111101.000000101000111101` ([conversion source](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/)).

Comment: By the way, change your format to `G20`, not `F20`.

Comment: Also 62.01 can be stored with full precision in both double and float. There should be no precision loss for what I'm doing. The full print of 62.01 has no decimal places up to 20 decimals for float OR for double. Why is precision lost ?

Comment: How do you represent `.01` in binary?

Comment: I understand now. The F20 was my problem, by using G20 I can see the true value.

Comment: @John: Outside of the formatting and conversion from source text, there does not appear to be any floating-point arithmetic errors in this question. The issue appears to be a consequence of Microsoft’s formatting, not the nature of floating-point. Please do not promiscuously close floating-point questions as duplicates of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), as it prevents people from getting correct answers.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Outside of the formatting and conversion from source text, there does not appear to be any floating-point arithmetic errors in this question. The issue appears to be a consequence of Microsoft’s formatting, not the nature of floating-point. Please do not promiscuously close floating-point questions as duplicates of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), as it prevents people from getting correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue observed in this question is caused largely by Microsoft’s choice of formatting, notably that Microsoft software fails to show the exact values because it limits the number of digits used to convert to decimal even when the format string requests more digits. Furthermore, it uses fewer digits when converting `float` than when converting `double`. Thus, if a `float` and `double` with the same value are formatted, the results may be different because the `float` formatting will use fewer significant digits.

Below, I go through the code statements in the question one by one. In summary, the crux of the matter is that the value 61.0099983215332 is formatted as “61.0100000000000” when it is a `float` and “61.0099983215332” when it is a `double`. This is purely Microsoft’s choice of formatting and is not caused by the nature of floating-point arithmetic.

The statement `double temp3 = 61.01` initializes `temp3` to exactly 61.00999999999999801048033987171947956085205078125. This change from 61.01 is necessary due to the nature of a binary floating-point format—it cannot represent exactly 61.01, so the nearest value representable in `double` is used.

The statement `dynamic temp = 61.01f` initializes `temp` to exactly 61.009998321533203125. As with `double`, the nearest representable value has been used, but, since `float` has less precision, the nearest value is not as close as in the `double` case.

The statement `double temp2 = (double)Convert.ChangeType(temp, typeof(double));` converts `temp` to a `double` that has the same value as `temp`, so it has the value 61.009998321533203125.

The statement `double newValue = temp2 - temp3;` correctly subtracts the two values, producing the exact result 0.00000167846679488548033987171947956085205078125, with no error.

The statement `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", temp));` formats the `float` named `temp`. Formatting a `float` involves callling [`Single.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2). Microsoft‘s documentation is a bit vague. It says that, by default, only seven (decimal) digits of precision are returned. It says to use `G` or `R` formats to get up to nine, and `F20` uses neither `G` nor `R`. So I believe only seven digits are used. When 61.009998321533203125 is rounded to seven significant decimal digits, the result is “61.01000”. The `ToString` method then pads this to twenty digits after the decimal point, producing “61.01000000000000000000”.

I will address your third `WriteLine` statement next and come back to the second one afterward.

The statement `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", temp3));` formats the `double` named `temp3`. Since `temp3` is a `double`, [`Double.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) is called. This method uses 15 digits of precision (unless `G` or`R` are used). When 61.00999999999999801048033987171947956085205078125 is rounded to 15 significant decimal digits, the result is “61.0100000000000”. The `ToString` method then pads this to twenty digits after the decimal point, producing “61.01000000000000000000”.

The statement `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", temp2));` formats the `double` named `temp2`. `temp2` is a `double` that contains the value from the `float` `temp`, so it contains 61.009998321533203125. When this is converted to 15 significant decimal digits, the result is “61.0099983215332”. The `ToString` method then pads this to twenty digits after the decimal point, producing “61.00999832153320000000”.

Finally, the statement `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  {0:F20}", newValue));` formats `newValue`. Formatting .00000167846679488548033987171947956085205078125 to 15 significant digits produces “0.00000167846679488548”.

Comment: This is absolutely the problem, my use of F20 instead of G20 obfuscated the issue at hand. Thanks for taking the time to explain it properly.

Answer (score -1):

this is because floats have smaller amounts of bits allocated to them than doubles. floats usually have 23 bits but doubles have 52. Therefore, by converting you are basically chopping off bits until you can fit it into a float. So that is why you loose precision.

Comment: But OP is converting float -> double, not double -> float.

Comment: I understand now. The F20 was my problem, by using G20 I can see the true value.